# How to set header and merge cells in DataGridView using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to merge cell in a header which I want to set on top of the column name in `DataGridView` and Header should be in center format.
Just like, I had shown the sample in the image.

[image: Sample]

I tried some code from [this link](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/169545/Merge-multiple-Cells-in-DataGirdView-header-in-Windows-Application/) but it didn’t work for me.

Comment: You cannot really merge them, you need to paint headers yourself.

Comment: But How ? @Reza Aghaei

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried some code from this below link but it didn’t work for me" ? Did you try some of the code? All of it? What was the result and how did it differ from what you want?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086133/3110834) for example or [this one](http://csharpdotnet2012.blogspot.com/2012/02/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html).

Comment: Hello o_weisman, i want the header should be in center when i want to merge the 3 cells.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891108/merge-mulitple-row-headers-in-a-datagridview-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you..

```
        wBook = _excel.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()
        wSheet.Range(wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColNature), wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColMAX)).Merge()
            wSheet.Range(wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColNature), wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColMAX)).WrapText = True
            wSheet.Range(wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColNature), wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColMAX)).Font.Bold = True
            wSheet.Range(wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColNature), wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColMAX)).Borders.LineStyle = 1

            wSheet.Range(wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColNature), wSheet.Cells(vRow, vColMAX)).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.Constants.xlCenter
```